# Does await really frees the current thread every time?

Tags: c#, async-await, threadpool

Consider the following async/await C# code example -

```
    public async Task<int> A()
    {
        // 1
        int id = await B();
        // 6
        return id;
    }

    public async Task<int> B()
    {
        // 2
        int id = await C();
        // 5
        return id;
    }

    public async Task<int> C()
    {
        // 3
        var id = await Task.Delay(1000); // db.GetCustomerId();        
        // 4
        return id;
    }
```

Lets consider the delay mocks the db.GetCustomerId() as some db call which will return id.
Let say I print the ManagedThreadId at comments 1 to 6;
I get the same thread id at positions 1,2,3 and different but same thread id at 4,5,6. 
When await is encountered in A() the current thread will return to ThreadPool if the call has not finished, and the new thread will continue at B(). But I think the same thread continues. 
Event when I run a loop of 1000 to run A() using Thread.Factory.StartNew() with a CPU intensive method in the program I dont see any difference.

So my question is does await actually returns the current thread to pool everytime or is it intelligent enough to do so only when a i/o call is made to network?

Comment: Task != Thread ...

Comment: Your sample code may or may not use an extra Thread. The question is incomplete without the top-level calling code. And not very interesting either way.

Comment: A very recommended reading [There is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: _"So my question is does await actually returns the current thread to pool everytime or is it intelligent enough to do so only when a i/o call is made to network?"_ -- there's so much wrong with that sentence, it's hard to know where to start. But the most applicable point as regards to your overall question is that, as has been well-documented and discussed on Stack Overflow (see e.g. marked duplicates), `await` does not return control to the caller if the task being awaited has already completed.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - I have mentioned already "the current thread will return to ThreadPool **if the call has not finished**,".

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I dont understand why you need the top level code. this is a perfectly valid example. You may have a DB/ network call which is denoted in method C(), and some of your code is just calling it and returning the result, here B(). Same with A(). My question is simple. What happens when the await is encountered in B()?

Comment: @PeterDuniho - I might be wrong about what happens after await is encountered but I have clearly mentioned the call is not complete. And do you think when I say Task.Delay(1000), the call will be completed?

Comment: Your assumptions about async and ThreadPool are wrong. It may be running on a Pool thread, or not. The toplevel code decides. The await in B() is just paused in a yield return alike statement.

Comment: _"I have clearly mentioned the call is not complete"_ -- I disagree that you've "clearly mentioned" that, but even if you had, it's not what you _asked_ in your question. _"When await is encountered in A()...the new thread will continue at B()"_ -- you seem to be very confused about the order of things. The `await` in `A()` doesn't happen until _after_ `B()` is called and _its_ `await` occurs, which in turn doesn't happen until _after_ `C()` is called and _its_ `await` occurs. This fully explains the thread IDs you are describing; pre-`await` is all on one thread, continuations on a second one

Comment: @PeterDuniho - "The await in A() doesn't happen until after B() is called and its await occurs" - this is even more confusing, though it seems logical for the threadIds printed. you mean to say the order of awaits is C()-B()-A()? but then how can it know that C() is last one?

Comment: To answer _"how can it know that C() is last one"_, I'd need you to explain in what way you feel that the `await` in `C()` is in fact the _"last one"_. It is in fact the _first_ `await` to be executed. It's no more the "last one" than in a completely non-async scenario, where e.g. `int A() { return B(); } int B() { return C(); } int C() { return 17; }`, the `return 17;` statement would be considered the "last one". The `return 17;` statement is the _first_ `return` statement to execute in that scenario. Likewise, the `awaits` in the code you have.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Oh sorry i meant last one in the sequence to be executed first in the reverse order. Ok this makes sense why the Ids are printed in that order.